# Intel FPGA input voltage between Vil and Vih : what's happening?

Tags: fpga, input, intel, cyclone

Considering these settings:

- Cyclone 10 LP (or Cyclone II / Cyclone III / Cyclone IV)
- IO configured as Input LVTTL 3.3V (Vilmax=0.8V Vihmin=1.7V)
- Voltage between 0.8V and 1.7V on this input
- No CLK rising edge on the D-register on this IO signal during this period of voltage between 0.8V and 1.7V (elsewise a metastability will occur, than can be stopped with a double D-register, but will occur each time, so it may damage the input over the long-term ?)
- Weak Pull-up and/or clamp can be set or not (with normally no influence)

Has somebody ever tried this? Without CLK rising edge is it normally possible without damaging the FPGA over the long-term?

Comment: Why do you think the FPGA will be damaged?

Comment: Because I think that an input is not directly connected to a D pin of a D-register (as described with IO schematic in Cyclone 10 datasheet), but with an AND gate before.

Comment: Why do you think that will damage the FPGA?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to do? Describe the problem clearly.

Comment: Because an AND gate working with a Vcc=3.3V is not working between its Vil and Vih : the push-pull output stage can create a current peak and then damage the chip.

Comment: The question is : a voltage between vil=0.8V and vih=1.7V can be maintained on an input of a cyclone without damaging it ? Here it's because this input is also use with an ADC (and there is no MUX).

Comment: How will 0.8-1.7V damage FPGA I/O? You should google "static discipline" and a Wikipedia link will pop up

Comment: Really sorry, but this is obvious, it's absolutly not my my issue. My question is not what's happening during transitions, but what's happening if the voltage stays in this transition between 0.8 and 1.7V, and I think it's not obvious. (And Google is also my friend).

Answer (score 3):

If a voltage in the range of V<sub>ILmax</sub> to V<sub>IHmin</sub> is applied to an input, it is undefined if the FPGA reads the input as *Low* or as *High*.

However, it will not damage the chip in any way. Voltages in this range occur every time the signal goes from low to high, and vice versa. Such voltages a part of the normal operation of a circuit.

Comment: Hum, it seems to be a peremptory answer. My question is not what's happening during transitions, but what's happening if the voltage stays in this transition between 0.8 and 1.7V for a while, and I think it's not obvious.

Comment: @zian The voltage transition is just an example. It applies too if the voltage stays in that range.

Comment: That's true. But after working few days on it : it was really not obvious, it should have been false. I needed a real technical demonstration of that with a Cyclone 10 IO. I'm always working on it => when this technical demonstration will be fine enough, I will post here a answer to "my own question".